# Defining datatypes in execution time?

Tags: parsing, haskell, types

I'm writing a PLY file parser and serialisation library as part of a research project in point clouds compression. The PLY file specifies the data format in a header before a payload section with all the data. The data is described by means of `elements` containing `properties`. For example:

```
element vertex 12 
property float x 
property float y 
property float z
```

informs that the payload will have a list with 12 elements called "vertex" with three float properties called x, y and z all of which are floating point numbers. For an arbitrary file, I don't know in advance which elements it contains nor the name, type or the amount of properties each one has. I solve this by parsing the header to create a list of elements

```
data Element = Element Name Qty [Property]
data Property = Property PropType Name
```

which tells me the overall structure of the payload with some functions to search if a given element is present and locate/parse the data in the payload section.

I have a working version, but I'm thinking about a new possibility (just for fun right now). What if I wanted to build a data structure that represents the data in the type level? Something like

```
data Vertex = Vertex { elX :: Float
                     , elY :: Float
                     , elY :: Float }
```

but with the detail I can only discover which fields (properties) my datatype (or types in case of more than one kind of element being described in the file) would have in execution time after parsing the file header so I can later build a function `parseVertex :: Parser [Vertex]` which then takes the payload data and parsers it?

May someone give me some advice on what to start looking for solving such a problem?

Comment: If you succeed in defining a data type at runtime, what would you then do with its values? How would you consume them? Or, to put it another way, what does it even mean to define a data type at runtime?

Comment: I'm not sure, actually. I started wondering about this problem with no useful application in mind. I had the aeson library in mind with the FromJSON type class but my knowledge about it is extremely limited.

Comment: You could generate a whole Haskell program after reading the header, compile it, and use it to process the body. That would be rather expensive ... unless the body is itself very expressive to process. But you might want to start with something more Haskelly, like the `vinyl` package.

Comment: It might be possible to do what aeson does: let the user define the structure of their datatype, then use Generic to automatically derive an encoder and decoder. But that may be overkill for your specific usecase.